# Spring Batch - Entering master child data from composite writer

Tags: java, duplicates, spring-batch

I have a file which has data in following form
MasterId  ChildId  attrMaster1 attrChild2
1               1           a1                        b1
1                          2                 a1                        b2
2                          3                 a2                        b3

I am using a composite writer, the first writer writes data into master table and other in child table.
MasterId attrMaster1
1                         a1
1                         a1
2                         a2
ChildId   attrChild2
1                          b1
2                          b2
3                          b3

I need Data in Master table should contain only one row for "1       a1". How can i check for that duplicacy? I do not want to hit the database every time to check if the master record with same id was inserted or not. I cannot enforce unique key constraint on the master table.

Comment: Can you cache the results of the db hit?  AKA, check for `1 a1` then cache the result so you are only hitting the db once for that entry over the course of the job.

Comment: No michael i cannot do that as well. As I am expecting batch size to be over 80 million. Caching will not help.

Comment: The other option would be sorting the file.

Comment: I did the sorting and then partitioning over master key. Created a concurrentHashMap to store partition wise current master key. when the value of that partition key changes it writes to file. Please suggest any improvement which can be done.